# Extract all possible sets of strings represented by the string expression (Part of Thompsons Construction)

Tags: string, algorithm, c++11, set, g++

(This is my first post here so do bear in mind if what I'm asking is seriously too much and that I should consider tackling this piece carefully one at a time, if my question is too specific, too broad, not focused down to a single problem, requiring significantly more info, or otherwise, please don't hesitate to comment down)

In C++, I'm currently in the process of doing Thompson's Construction in a certain way **without using the regex header** and I'm anxiously stuck on how to proceed and why,

Say I have the following String expression in which '.' is Concatenation, '|' is Union, and '*' is KleeneStar, we can assume the syntax is already checked beforehand, and that they can be read as:

`a` or

`(a)|(b)` or

`(a).(b)` or

`((a)|(b)).(c)` or

`((c)|(d)).((a)|(b))` or

`(a)*` or

`((a)*)|((b)*)` or

The goal here is to extract, call, or read the string expression that would lay out a set of strings as its expected output resulting from their corresponding expression (note an empty string could be output as '_') in which:

`a` outputs `{a}`

`(a)|(b)` outputs `{a, b}`

`(a).(b)` outputs `{ab}`

`((a)|(b)).(c)` outputs `{ac, bc}`

`((c)|(d)).((a)|(b))` outputs `{ca, da, cb, db}`

`(a)*` outputs `{_, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, ...}` (*we can consider putting a limit here)*

`((a)*)|((b)*)` outputs `{_, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, bbb, ...}` *(we can consider putting a limit here)*

I'm sure there's a better way to do this beforehand using algorithms, pseudo-code, parsing, and more, or that my lack of practice leaves me serious gaps in my coding knowledge to perform such a thing.

As of now, I'm seriously wondering a number of factors such as what functions to make, what recursion calls to make, pointers, stacks, vectors, where and when, etc., and that such a process can perhaps really stress the program to calculate ALL possibilities for whatever I'm achieving, say, matching an input string from a user to match the set of strings listed.

and that perhaps one of the posts I've looked over in forums wasn't fully read over enough to understand. I'm completely overwhelmed in my perspective and would like a walkthrough on what to do one step at a time, further guidance and assistance are seriously greatly appreciated. A complete walkthrough for any solutions or even your own codes posted would be of great help for me to learn. Any suggestions would really help. Again any critical terms that I've forgotten to mention or anything specific please post your comments, Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
I've been told that what I'm suggesting can be quite concerning with the KleeneStar operator and that generating the output would may become nontrivial? I was wondering if setting an int limit would be possible or that could still seriously cause even more complications.

Comment: Neither of those linked questions are about the full set of regular expressions, since they don't allow the Kleene star operator.

Comment: In any case, you need to focus. A lot. Are you trying to parse the regular expression itself into a usable data structure? Are you trying to use a description of a regular expression to recognize a target string (or strings), or are you trying to use a description of a regular expression to produce some or all possible strings in the language for that regular expression? What are you optimising for? Time? Space? Legibility?

Comment: And why don't you pick up a textbook which explains regular expressions, and spend a couple or three hours reading it? That will get you a lot further than glancing at random web pages written by people who don't know as much as they think they do.

Comment: @rici the linked questions aren't exactly a solution to my question (apologizes for not mentioning it earlier) but rather for guidance on how to proceed, some yes are missing critical operators. I am trying to use a description of a regular expression to produce some or all possible strings in the language for that regular expression yes. Legibility is considered, time and space are not significantly important as of now. Forgive me if my comment is bland or somewhat still confusing as to what was asked as I'm not particularly accurate in my description.

Comment: Not allowing the Kleene star is not just missing an operator; it radically changes the nature of the question. Without the Kleene star, the regular expression describes a finite number of strings, making generation trivial (depth-first search would do it). With the Kleene star, any recursion could go off into an infinite recursive loop; the most feasible way to enumerate strings is then a breadth-first search, but that's not nearly as straight-forward. Please edit your question to better explain your needs. Thanks.

Comment: And try to restrict it to a single question which could be answered in three or four short paragraphs at most.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is fully define the grammar that the code supports. In the examples, every single subexpression is fully parenthesized. Is that a requirement, or are you going to allow expressions like `a|b.c`? And if you do support `a|b.c`, does it mean `(a|b).c` or `a|(b.c)`?

Comment: @rici Yikes, Even if you supposedly set a limit once a Kleene star operator is read, would it still complicate things even more than it should? I thought you could set an **int** limit to stop producing the specific char or set of chars before moving onto the next set of combinations. I've already made a function that would read through each elements of the set based on the string expression to find a matching input string just as it would, and the fact that you've stated a Kleene star could "go off into an infinite recursive loop" just made me want restart the whole process all over again.

Comment: @user3386109, They are required to be fully parenthesized yes, your example of `a|b.c` doesn't work, same goes `(a|b).c` or `a|(b.c)`. Every char must be parenthesized which is handeled but if it's alone like a, it continues as normal.

Comment: Ok, so at the top level, you only have three constructions to handle `(<expr1>)|(<expr2>)`, `(<expr1>).(<expr2>)` and `(<expr1>)*`. After identifying the top level construction, you recursively evaluate the subexpressions (`expr1` and `expr2`).  Each recursive call returns a set of possible answers. You then Union, Concatentate, or KleeneStar as appropriate, and return the resulting set.

Comment: At the moment that is what I'm going for yes, a bit of clarity or pseudo code would help step by step.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Thompson's construction to convert the regular expression into a nondeterministic finite automaton with ε-transitions, then run Dijkstra's algorithm in a graph where the nodes are (q, x) pairs where q is a state and x is a string, and the arcs are from (q, x) to (δ(q, σ), x σ) where σ is either a symbol (weight 1, back of the double-ended queue) or ε (weight 0, front of the double-ended queue). By enumerating in this order, we can easily add a size limit.

We parse the regular expression with recursive descent. I'm not going to explain further; there are a million calculator tutorials out there.

Don't-run-this-in-production-grade C++ below.

```cpp
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

struct State;

struct Transition {
  char symbol;
  State *successor;
};

struct State {
  std::vector<State *> epsilon_transitions;
  std::vector<Transition> transitions;
  std::unordered_set<std::string> visited_strings;
};

struct Automaton {
  State *initial_state;
  State *final_state;
};

Automaton Eps() {
  Automaton c;
  c.initial_state = c.final_state = new State;
  return c;
}

Automaton Sym(char symbol) {
  Automaton c;
  c.initial_state = new State;
  c.final_state = new State;
  c.initial_state->transitions.push_back({symbol, c.final_state});
  return c;
}

Automaton Star(Automaton a) {
  Automaton c;
  c.initial_state = c.final_state = new State;
  c.final_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(a.initial_state);
  a.final_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(c.final_state);
  return c;
}

Automaton Cat(Automaton a, Automaton b) {
  Automaton c;
  c.initial_state = a.initial_state;
  c.final_state = b.final_state;
  a.final_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(b.initial_state);
  return c;
}

Automaton Alt(Automaton a, Automaton b) {
  Automaton c;
  c.initial_state = new State;
  c.final_state = new State;
  c.initial_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(a.initial_state);
  c.initial_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(b.initial_state);
  a.final_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(c.final_state);
  b.final_state->epsilon_transitions.push_back(c.final_state);
  return c;
}

void Enumerate(Automaton a, std::size_t size_limit = 4) {
  std::deque<std::tuple<State *, std::string>> queue = {
      {a.initial_state, std::string()}};
  do {
    auto [state, string] = queue.front();
    if (string.size() > size_limit) {
      std::cout << "...\n";
      break;
    }
    queue.pop_front();
    if (!state->visited_strings.insert(string).second) {
      continue;
    }
    if (state == a.final_state) {
      std::cout << "\"" << string << "\"\n";
    }
    for (State *successor : state->epsilon_transitions) {
      queue.push_front({successor, string});
    }
    for (auto [symbol, successor] : state->transitions) {
      queue.push_back({successor, string + std::string(1, symbol)});
    }
  } while (!queue.empty());
  std::cout << "\n";
}

#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>
#include <istream>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>

char Peek(std::istream &input) {
  input >> std::ws;
  return input.peek();
}

bool Match(std::istream &input, char c) {
  if (Peek(input) == c) {
    input.get();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

std::optional<char> ParseSymbol(std::istream &input) {
  if (std::isalpha(Peek(input))) {
    return input.get();
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}

std::optional<Automaton> Parse(std::istream &input);

std::optional<Automaton> ParsePrimitive(std::istream &input) {
  if (auto maybe_symbol = ParseSymbol(input)) {
    return Sym(maybe_symbol.value());
  }
  if (Match(input, '(')) {
    if (auto maybe_a = Parse(input)) {
      if (Match(input, ')')) {
        return maybe_a.value();
      }
    }
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}

std::optional<Automaton> ParseFactor(std::istream &input) {
  if (auto maybe_a = ParsePrimitive(input)) {
    if (Match(input, '*')) {
      return Star(*maybe_a);
    }
    return *maybe_a;
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}

std::optional<Automaton> ParseTerm(std::istream &input) {
  if (auto maybe_a = ParseFactor(input)) {
    Automaton a = maybe_a.value();
    while (Match(input, '.')) {
      if (auto maybe_b = ParseFactor(input)) {
        a = Cat(a, maybe_b.value());
      } else {
        return std::nullopt;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}

std::optional<Automaton> Parse(std::istream &input) {
  if (auto maybe_a = ParseTerm(input)) {
    Automaton a = maybe_a.value();
    while (Match(input, '|')) {
      if (auto maybe_b = ParseTerm(input)) {
        a = Alt(a, maybe_b.value());
      } else {
        return std::nullopt;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}

std::optional<Automaton> Parse(const std::string &input) {
  std::stringstream stream(input);
  if (auto maybe_a = Parse(stream)) {
    if (Peek(stream) == EOF) {
      return maybe_a.value();
    }
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
  Enumerate(Parse("a").value());
  Enumerate(Parse("a|b").value());
  Enumerate(Parse("a.b").value());
  Enumerate(Parse("(a|b).c").value());
  Enumerate(Parse("(c|d).(a|b)").value());
  Enumerate(Parse("a*").value());
  Enumerate(Parse("(a|b)*").value());
}
```

Output:

```
"a"

"b"
"a"

"ab"

"bc"
"ac"

"db"
"da"
"cb"
"ca"

""
"a"
"aa"
"aaa"
"aaaa"
...

""
"b"
"a"
"bb"
"ba"
"ab"
"aa"
"bbb"
"bba"
"bab"
"baa"
"abb"
"aba"
"aab"
"aaa"
"bbbb"
"bbba"
"bbab"
"bbaa"
"babb"
"baba"
"baab"
"baaa"
"abbb"
"abba"
"abab"
"abaa"
"aabb"
"aaba"
"aaab"
"aaaa"
...
```

Comment: This took awhile to understand but your answer is surely noted, thanks for your efforts though _thumbs up_, still waiting for others on how to tackle this problem since your answer doesn't necessarily read the string expression as its parameters, but could probably be pieced together?

Comment: @Axon727 I added a parser.

Comment: I've just noticed thank you again for your efforts. Though my OP was tagged under C++11 and yours requires c++17 to work, I won't bother you again for your troubles of having to rework your code for the third time if you wish to or not, again thanks for your efforts